# Wordpress Widget on a page not using Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, widget

I use a wordpress blog format for the news section of my website but not the main part and I want to have a"most recent" widget drawing from the wordpress section but displaying on a page that is not using the blog it is written mostly in html and javascript.  Is this possible and if so does anyone have any examples they could point me to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible - the Widget API is loaded somewhere in the middle of the WordPress loading process so you need a PHP rendering engine loading the entire WP and getting the widget code evaluated at the end. You will need some PHP to get the data from the database or at least AJAX code calling to external scripts that pull posts from the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It may be possible with an iframe, but I (as would most developers) highly advise against that. W3C compliance with iframes can be tricky, but if you're not worried about that then give it a go.</strike> On second thought, iframes wouldn't even be a viable option. Just pull the RSS in to your HTML pages using something like this (http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/displaying-rss-feeds-with-xhtml-css-and-jquery.html) from HTMLGoodies.com.

Another alternative could be to use a method outlined by FLD Trace here: http://www.fldtrace.com/wordpress/display-latest-post-outside-of-wordpress-with-json-and-jquery, and showcased here: http://www.fldtrace.com/lab/jsonAPI.html.

I've used it before with mild success on a few projects, and styled the FLDT widget accordingly. Be sure to give credit where credit is due if you use this and it fits the bill of what you're looking for--though I don't see any licensing restrictions for FLD Trace's method.